# Vue Router updates URl twice for single call to push()

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/upload'});
```

updates the browser URL to be ...#/upload fine. But

```
this.$router.push( '/edit/file/4' );
```

briefly flashes the expected URL in the address bar before it is updated to '...#/' - the transiation has worked, in that my edit view loads, but I have to press back twice (once to the /edit/file/4, once to my real previous state) instead of once.

Why ? And how can I make it work as I expect ?

My Router routes are

```
routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      children:[
        {
          name: 'upload',
          path:'upload',
          component:HomeUpload
        },

        {
          name: 'edit-file',
          path: 'edit/file/:file_id',
          component:HomeUpload,
          props: true // or field_id prop not filled in
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the template had

`<a @click="edit(page)" href="#">Edit</a></td>`

instead of

`<a @click="edit(page)">Edit</a></td>`